# Why I get error while trying to use LaTeX in plots' label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to show:

[image]

...as my plots' x axis label. For this purpose I use the `pylab.figtext()` function, i.e:

```
py.figtext(0.5, 0.05, "$k=2,\left \langle \left | -k \right |;k \right \rangle, 
k\in \mathbb{N}_{+}\cup\left \{ 0 \right \}$", rotation='horizontal', size='12')
```

Unfortunately, I get error:

```
ValueError: 
$k=2,\left \langle \left | -k 
ight |;k 
ight 
angle, k\in \mathbb{N}_{+}\cup\left \{ 0 
ight \}$
^
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Why is that? I thought, that I can use LaTeX freely. How should I format my text in `figtext()` method in order to achieve the aforementioned mathematical sentence? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [LATEX Mathematical Symbols](https://www.caam.rice.edu/~heinken/latex/symbols.pdf) & [matplotlib: Rendering math equations using TeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be fixed by a 1 letter correction:

```
py.figtext(0.5, 0.05, r"$k=2,\left \langle \left | -k \right |;k \right \rangle, 
k\in \mathbb{N}_{+}\cup\left \{ 0 \right \}$", rotation='horizontal', size='12')
```

Note the **r** before the string literal. The cause of the error is that several of the character combinations in your latex string are valid Python [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for such things as tabs and new-lines. A string literal prefixed with an **r** (e.g. `r"foo\nbar"`) makes Python interpret the string as a [raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), i.e. without converting the escaped character combinations to special characters.

Answer (score 6):

The backslashes in your string are interpreted as Python string escapes.  For instance `\r` is interpreted as a carriage return.  Use a raw string by making your string `r"$k=2,\left \langle \left..."`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, placing an 'r' at the front works.

Check this line : `plt.xlabel(r'$\rho$'); plt.ylabel('$\sigma_{yy}$(MPa)');`

[without 'r'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5W05.png) and [with 'r'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfeJA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when working with one of the examples on [this](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html) page and **r** before my string literal didn't help. I escaped $ signs and it worked.

```
r"Standardized [\$\$N  (\mu=0, \; \sigma=1)\$\$]",
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, refrain from using a raw string as a way to properly escape characters. This kills the possibility to use a formatted string.

---

Instead of `\` use `\\`. The first backslash tells the parser: "the next character is a special character", and the second backslash: "this special character is `\`".

If your string is:

```
ax.plot(epoch, e, label=f'Q={q_var} ($\sigma^2=${v})')
```

just add `\`:

```
ax.plot(epoch, e, label=f'Q={q_var} ($\\sigma^2=${v})')
```

Of course sometimes it can be too much work or difficult to read, and using the raw string is preferable, but this is at the cost of losing the f-string feature.